# What Does The Spring Boot "debug" Config Property Set?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot

If I configure my Spring Boot web app with the following property in my `application.yaml` config file:

```
debug: true
```

I've noticed that my logging config gets ignored and everything is set to a DEBUG level. Makes sense.

Does `debug=true` affect anything else though? Or is this simply a logging thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

> you can also specify debug=true in your application.properties.
>
> When the debug mode is enabled, a selection of core loggers (embedded
>   container, Hibernate and Spring Boot) are configured to output more
>   information.