# Spring boot Debug log traces on startup

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, spring-cloud, logback

A few days ago I added Spring cloud dependencies (openfeign and so on) to my Spring Boot app.

The application suddenly started to write log traces on startup like this ones:

```
2019-11-22 12:22:49,363 [DEBUG] org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener  Application started with classpath: [file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/charsets.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/deploy.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/access-bridge-64.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/javaws.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/jce.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/jfr.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/jsse.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/management-agent.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/plugin.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/resources.jar, file:/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/rt.jar, file:/D:/Proyectos/PetApp/Back/PetApp_Core/target/classes/, file:/D:/Proyectos/PetApp/Back/PetApp_ModelLib/target/classes/, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.9.4/aspectjweaver-1.9.4.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/zaxxer/HikariCP/3.2.0/HikariCP-3.2.0.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.3/javax.transaction-api-1.3.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/5.3.10.Final/hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/javax/persistence/javax.persistence-api/2.2/javax.persistence-api-2.2.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.23.2-GA/javassist-3.23.2-GA.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/net/bytebuddy/byte-buddy/1.9.13/byte-buddy-1.9.13.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/2.0.5.Final/jandex-2.0.5.Final.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/dom4j/dom4j/2.1.1/dom4j-2.1.1.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/5.0.4.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/2.1.9.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/2.1.9.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-orm-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-context-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-tx-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-aspects-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-security-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.11.2/log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.11.2/log4j-api-2.11.2.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.26/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.26.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.23/snakeyaml-1.23.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-config/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-security-config-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-json-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.9/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.9.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.9/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.9.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.9/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.9.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/9.0.21/tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/9.0.21/tomcat-embed-el-9.0.21.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/9.0.21/tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.21.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.17.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.17.Final.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter-openfeign/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-openfeign-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-starter/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-cloud-starter-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-context/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-cloud-context-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-rsa/1.0.7.RELEASE/spring-security-rsa-1.0.7.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcpkix-jdk15on/1.60/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.60.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.60/bcprov-jdk15on-1.60.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-ribbon-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-archaius/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-cloud-netflix-archaius-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/github/openfeign/form/feign-form-spring/3.8.0/feign-form-spring-3.8.0.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/github/openfeign/form/feign-form/3.8.0/feign-form-3.8.0.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.4/commons-fileupload-1.4.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/2.2/commons-io-2.2.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/cloud/spring-cloud-commons/2.1.3.RELEASE/spring-cloud-commons-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-crypto/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-security-crypto-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/github/openfeign/feign-core/10.2.3/feign-core-10.2.3.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/github/openfeign/feign-slf4j/10.2.3/feign-slf4j-10.2.3.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/github/openfeign/feign-hystrix/10.2.3/feign-hystrix-10.2.3.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/netflix/archaius/archaius-core/0.7.6/archaius-core-0.7.6.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/3.0.1/jsr305-3.0.1.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.8/commons-configuration-1.8.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/netflix/hystrix/hystrix-core/1.5.18/hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/reactivex/rxjava/1.3.8/rxjava-1.3.8.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/hdrhistogram/HdrHistogram/2.1.9/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-test/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-test-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.16/mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/postgresql/postgresql/42.2.5/postgresql-42.2.5.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.199/h2-1.4.199.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/security/spring-security-core/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/cloudinary/cloudinary-http44/1.24.0/cloudinary-http44-1.24.0.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/cloudinary/cloudinary-core/1.24.0/cloudinary-core-1.24.0.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.8.1/commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.9/httpclient-4.5.9.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.11/httpcore-4.4.11.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpmime/4.5.9/httpmime-4.5.9.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.5/gson-2.8.5.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/assertj/assertj-core/3.11.1/assertj-core-3.11.1.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/auth0/java-jwt/3.3.0/java-jwt-3.3.0.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.9/jackson-databind-2.9.9.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.9/jackson-core-2.9.9.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.11/commons-codec-1.11.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger2/2.9.2/springfox-swagger2-2.9.2.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-annotations/1.5.20/swagger-annotations-1.5.20.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/swagger/swagger-models/1.5.20/swagger-models-1.5.20.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spi/2.9.2/springfox-spi-2.9.2.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-core/2.9.2/springfox-core-2.9.2.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-schema/2.9.2/springfox-schema-2.9.2.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-common/2.9.2/springfox-swagger-common-2.9.2.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-spring-web/2.9.2/springfox-spring-web-2.9.2.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/20.0/guava-20.0.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.4.0/classmate-1.4.0.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.26/slf4j-api-1.7.26.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/springframework/plugin/spring-plugin-metadata/1.2.0.RELEASE/spring-plugin-metadata-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/org/mapstruct/mapstruct/1.2.0.Final/mapstruct-1.2.0.Final.jar, file:/D:/Tools/.m2/repository/io/springfox/springfox-swagger-ui/2.9.2/springfox-swagger-ui-2.9.2.jar, file:/D:/app/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20Community%20Edition%202018.2.7/lib/idea_rt.jar]
2019-11-22 12:22:49,645 [DEBUG] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication  Loading source class org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapImportSelectorConfiguration
2019-11-22 12:22:49,704 [DEBUG] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext  Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2e005c4b
2019-11-22 12:22:49,741 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
2019-11-22 12:22:49,776 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
2019-11-22 12:22:49,990 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.BeanTypeRegistry'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,142 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,154 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,155 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationBeanFactoryMetadata'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,156 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,159 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,160 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,164 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,164 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,169 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'configurationPropertiesBeans'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,170 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,179 [INFO ] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker  Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a7e4833f] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-11-22 12:22:50,208 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'bootstrapImportSelectorConfiguration'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,210 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,224 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.cloud.config-org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.PropertySourceBootstrapProperties'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,239 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,242 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'encrypt-org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.encrypt.KeyProperties'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,245 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'environmentDecryptApplicationListener'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,256 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinder'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,260 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver  Autowiring by type from bean name 'configurationPropertiesRebinder' via factory method to bean named 'configurationPropertiesBeans'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,273 [DEBUG] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry  Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration'
2019-11-22 12:22:50,298 [DEBUG] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener  


============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor' (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesBeans matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeans; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration#configurationPropertiesRebinder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.cloud.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinder; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.RsaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - Keystore nor key found in Environment (EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.KeyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)

   EncryptionBootstrapConfiguration.VanillaEncryptionConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnMissingClass found unwanted class 'org.springframework.security.rsa.crypto.RsaSecretEncryptor' (OnClassCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    None



###########################################################
__________        __    __     _____ ____________________
\______   \ _____/  |__/  |_  /  _  \\______   \______   \
 |     ___// __ \   __\   __\/  /_\  \|     ___/|     ___/
 |    |   \  ___/|  |  |  | /    |    \    |    |    |
 |____|    \___  >__|  |__| \____|__  /____|    |____|
               \/                   \/
                                                PetApp Core
###########################################################

2019-11-22 12:22:51,844 [INFO ] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication  No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-11-22 12:23:00,248 [INFO ] com.mashosoft.petapp.core.config.DDBB.DDBBConfig  H2 DDBB selected
```

As you can see, it is writing a lot of DEBUG traces on startUp and the, after banner, logs works nice.

my logback-spring.xml is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="false">

    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%green(%d{ISO8601}) [%highlight(%-5level)] %yellow(%C{1.}) %magenta(%X{requestKey}) %msg%n%throwable</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="${logging.level.org.springframework}" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="com.mashosoft.petapp.orchestrator" level="${logging.level.orchestrator}" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </logger>
    <Root level="${logging.level.ROOT}">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </Root>

</configuration>
```

and I have 3 properties in my application.properties

```
# Log properties in application.properties
logging.level.orchestrator=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework=ERROR
logging.level.ROOT=OFF
```

I have not being able to make these traces disappear because they are very annoying and other app I have doesn't show them every time I start up the application.

I also have add a Spring Boot admin server and client and I can see that all org.springframework traces are set to error.

Everuthing started when adding spring-cloud

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Greenwich.SR3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <!--PETAPP-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mashosoft.petapp</groupId>
            <artifactId>PetAppModelLib</artifactId>
            <version>V-0.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--SPRING-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

### If i set -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=OFF it works perfect.

```
###########################################################
__________        __    __     _____ ____________________
\______   \ _____/  |__/  |_  /  _  \\______   \______   \
 |     ___// __ \   __\   __\/  /_\  \|     ___/|     ___/
 |    |   \  ___/|  |  |  | /    |    \    |    |    |
 |____|    \___  >__|  |__| \____|__  /____|    |____|
               \/                   \/
                                                PetApp Core
###########################################################

2019-11-30 13:12:55,391 [INFO ] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication  The following profiles are active: local
2019-11-30 13:13:05,102 [INFO ] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger  Started PetAppApiGatewayApplication in 13.05 seconds (JVM running for 13.743)
```

### If I directly set the level in logback-spring.xml like:

```
<logger name="org.hibernate" level="error" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="error" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </logger>
```

its doesnt shows the first traces but show anothers

```
###########################################################
__________        __    __     _____ ____________________
\______   \ _____/  |__/  |_  /  _  \\______   \______   \
 |     ___// __ \   __\   __\/  /_\  \|     ___/|     ___/
 |    |   \  ___/|  |  |  | /    |    \    |    |    |
 |____|    \___  >__|  |__| \____|__  /____|    |____|
               \/                   \/
                                                PetApp Core
###########################################################

2019-11-30 13:11:13,079 [INFO ] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication  The following profiles are active: local
2019-11-30 13:11:14,470 [WARN ] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId  Endpoint ID 'hystrix.stream' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2019-11-30 13:11:14,803 [INFO ] org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope  BeanFactory id=105fdd6b-1452-33a9-a76c-73ca1dbb84c7
2019-11-30 13:11:15,079 [INFO ] org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker  Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$29974e55] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-11-30 13:11:16,247 [INFO ] org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8088 (http)
2019-11-30 13:11:16,460 [INFO ] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext  Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3361 ms
2019-11-30 13:11:18,260 [WARN ] org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.RemoteDevToolsAutoConfiguration$RemoteRestartConfiguration  Listening for remote restart updates on /PetApp/.~~spring-boot!~/restart
2019-11-30 13:11:18,942 [INFO ] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver  Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2019-11-30 13:11:19,081 [WARN ] org.springframework.cloud.netflix.archaius.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration  No spring.application.name found, defaulting to 'application'
2019-11-30 13:11:19,287 [INFO ] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ExecutorConfigurationSupport  Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-11-30 13:11:19,327 [INFO ] org.springframework.boot.devtools.autoconfigure.OptionalLiveReloadServer  LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2019-11-30 13:11:20,684 [INFO ] org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilterInitializer  Starting filter initializer
2019-11-30 13:11:21,174 [INFO ] org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  Tomcat started on port(s): 8088 (http) with context path '/PetApp'
2019-11-30 13:11:22,456 [INFO ] org.springframework.boot.StartupInfoLogger  Started PetAppApiGatewayApplication in 12.914 seconds (JVM running for 13.631)
```

Comment: Try setting the log level via command line using *-Dlogging.level.ROOT*. I don't think that properties are loaded prior to logging this.

Comment: I think `logging.level.ROOT=INFO|WARN|DEBUG` and not `OFF`. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties) for more info

Comment: any of this solutions has work... I still see these traces :(

Comment: everything started when adding spring-cloud dependency

Comment: If i set as @Abhishek said -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=OFF it works perfect. ¿What I am doing wrong in my configuration? help please. Also if i directly set the level in logback-spring.xml it works... it seemd it is not taking the ${}

Comment: you can add `logging.level.org.springframework=INFO` in application.properties file

Comment: @lakshman I already has add it.....it is definned on the post....

Comment: Can you check if you have `profile` configured in your maven pom that uses different logging configuration? This usually happens if there is another configuration that is overriding your configuration.

Comment: @sunil I don't have any maven profiles in pom

Comment: Ok. How many logging xml files do you have? just one - `logback-spring.xml` ?
Can you try moving the `<Root>` tags before `<Logger>` tags and see if it makes any impact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed by adding

```
    <property resource="application.properties" />
```

in logback-spring.xml. I dont know why i have to addit.

Now i jave another project that uses application.yaml and by adding

```
    <property resource="application.yaml" />
```

it doesn't even work....

Answer (score 9):

I don't have enough information to say this definitively, but somehow, somewhere, there is an application.yml or application.properties file with `debug: true` set.

This magical property will do two things. First, it will override all logging levels with DEBUG. Second, it will display that long list of positive and negative matches at the bottom of your output. You might want to check out [What Does The Spring Boot "debug" Config Property Set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446312/what-does-the-spring-boot-debug-config-property-set) for details, but you can test this by setting `debug: false` in your root `application.yml` file. Leave everything else the way you want it set. If the unexpected debug messages go away, that's your answer. I don't know what dependencies you are including, but one of them must have set that property if you didn't do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same case and basically I had to disable the debugging messages by unchecking the "Enable debug output" in "Spring boot" run configuration of my "Run":

[image]

Comment: I solved the issue a long time ago running also the jar file. I will post the answer but thanks

Comment: the answer could also be a reference to other users.

Comment: +1 This worked for me. What is the equivalent of this for command line? For instance, if I have a JAR file, and I want to see the same output there? Is there a command line argument or a file that I must edit? And what should I add there?

Comment: @shikharraje the equivalent is --debug

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the below `logback-spring.xml` config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <springProfile name="dev">
        <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml"/>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        </root>
    </springProfile>
</configuration>
```

Hope this will solve the issue

Comment: Hi and thanks in advance but I am already using a file named as logback-spring.xml and the format of tags is almost the same. Also in the example you are showing me you are also adding a spring profile that I don't have. Anyway I will try to copy-paste without profile to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Use the following properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web=OFF
logging.level.com.path.to.base.package=INFO
```

where put your base package path in place of **com.path.to.base.package**.

Comment: As you can read in the post I have already tried without success

Answer (score 0):

Add -
**spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER**    into your property files

2)Clean Maven and build it